# Is there a way to use a skyve validator (e.g. email) to test a value which isn't an attribute on a bean?

Tags: java, skyve

I have a transient document which help to upload a bunch of staff to the system. now, I want to have a validation check on the emails while uploading and processing those records, to issue relevant messages to the uploader.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Skyve email validator as outlined in the dev guide at https://skyvers.github.io/skyve-dev-guide/converters/#using-a-validator-without-a-bean